# How can I display value in each textbox in loop that the value based on the value selected in its combobox?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I tried to write codes which display value in textbox based on value selected in combobox, but I have one problem I puted combobox and texbox in loop but only first row can display value of selected item in combobox where I want each row to display value based on value selected in its combobox
Below are my codes

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
for($counter=0;$counter<=1;$counter++)
{
$queItem= mysqli_query($connect,"select * from oitm");
echo"<select name=\"segment_id\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"segment_id\" STYLE=\"width: 300px\" >";
echo"<option value=\"\" selected=\"selected\">Select a product</option>";

            while($rowStockIn = mysqli_fetch_array($queItem))
            {
            $ItemCode2=$rowStockIn['ItemCode'];
            $ItemName2=$rowStockIn['ItemName'];
            $ItemPrice2=$rowStockIn['ItemPrice'];

            echo "<option value=\"$ItemCode2\" data-itemprice = \"$ItemPrice2\">
        $ItemCode2 $ItemName2";
            }
echo"</select>";
?>
</span>
<?php   
echo"<input id=\"title\" name=\"title\" type=\"text\" value=\"$ItemPrice2\"
><br/>";
}
?>





        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#segment_id").on('change', function () {
        var id = $(this).val(); 
        var itemprice = $('option:selected',this).data('itemprice');
        $("#title").val(itemprice);
    });
});
        </script>
```

I think I have to edit jQuery in order to allow each row to work

Please anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well, if you are using a combo box then clearly the user should be able to select more than one option.  Your first problem is that $itemCode2 in your while loop is just a variable not an array.  Therefore, as you described in your issue you'll only ever get one value because it will be overwritten each time in the loop.

Make $itemCode2 an array - for example:

`$itemCode2[] = $rowStockin['itemCode']`

Then you should be able to output the various options that the user can select.

Also, be careful using select * in your queries.  Try to be specific in your column selections.  select * could leave your script exposed to a sql injection attack.